# How to access method of Fragment from Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, refresh

I have a viewpager, which shows 3 different Fragments in tabs. I want to refresh the current tab always when I swipe to it. 
I found on the internet the facility to set up a onTabSelected() listener. But my problem is, I don't know how to access the populatlistview() method of the particular fragments. 
I've searched on google for a couple of days but I couldn,t find anything helpful. 
Can you please help me?

Comment: populatlistview() is in all your fragment or just in only one?

Comment: do you try to access to populatlistview()  only if this fragment is the current, right?